# evopdf 6.12; html string to pdf, does not render image on the pdf

Tags: html-to-pdf, evopdf

I am trying to use EvoPdf library (demo version). I have html string with a full path to an image for example:

```
finalString.Append(@"<img src='http://www.ladessertelocale.com/2618-home_default/tomate-bio-1-kg.jpg'/>");
```

I used the following code to generate the pdf. The pdf file is generated with all the content but the image does not show on the pdf generated. A red x is shown in place of the image.

```
HtmlToPdfConverter converter = new HtmlToPdfConverter{
LicenseKey = "",
HtmlViewerWidth = 1024,
PdfDocumentOptions = { PdfPageSize = PdfPageSize.A4, PdfPageOrientation = PdfPageOrientation.Portrait, InternalLinksEnabled = true }
};
byte[] outPdfBuffer = null;
outPdfBuffer = converter.ConvertHtml(finalString.ToString(), "");
return File(outPdfBuffer, "application/pdf");
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try changing the image src to the relative path of your image folder. Or alternately, can you render the image as Data/URI Base 64?

Comment: That worked. Thanks!. I changed the image html to below (base64 string truncated). finalString.Append(@"<img src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSAGXR'/>");

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Batuta, I changed the image html to below (base64 string truncated).

```
finalString.Append(@"<img src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgSAGXR'/>");
```

I used this website to upload the image and get base64 string representation of the image.
http://imagetobase64.com/